# How to add items dynamically to a polymer paper-tree?

Tags: polymer

I am using polymer paper-tree element in my code.Its displays the tree perfectly with static data,however when I try to add an item dynamically it doesn't work. I am attaching a screenshot here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDAwJ.png)

//Array

```
    this.itemArray = {"name": "Project",
                                                "icon": "theaters",
                                                "open": true,
                                                "children": [{
                                                    "name": "Quotes",
                                                    "icon": "theaters",
                                                     "open": true,
                                                    "children": [{
                                                      "name": "Breaking Bad",
                                                        "icon": "theaters"
                                                    }]
                                                }, {
                                                    "name": "Templates",
                                                    "icon": "theaters",
                                                     "open": true,
                                                    "children": [{
                                                        "name": "Breaking Bad",
                                                        "icon": "theaters"
                                                    }, {
                                                        "name": "Game of Thrones",
                                                        "icon": "theaters"
                                                    }]
                                                }]
                                      }

   //Js code which accepts value from a text box and adds it to the array.


 this.$.additem.addEventListener("click", function(){

enter code herevar data = self.$.txtData.value;
                                                                           self.itemArray.children[1].children.push(
                                          {'name':data,
                                           'icon':'theaters'});

                                          self.addData(self.itemArray,data);
                                          self.$.txtData.value = " ";


                                  });

// addData function



addData:function(itemsarr){
                      console.log("calling items array function",this.tree);
                      var tempArr = [];
                      tempArr = itemsarr;
                      if(this.tree){
                       this.$.temp.removeChild(this.tree);
                       //tempArr = itemsarr; //= this.itemArray2;
                      }

                      this.tree = document.createElement('paper-tree-node');
                      this.tree.setAttribute('id','treemenu');
                      this.$.temp.appendChild(this.tree);
                      this.tree.data = tempArr;
                      console.log(tempArr);

      }
```

Comment: did you try polymer array functions ? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation

Comment: yeah... array comes out to be correct but it doesn't get applied on tree correctly. Only first dynamic item gets added correctly with text and icon but after that it only shows folder icon. Not sure what is the issue.

Comment: can you edit your question and add some code? so we can see what do you have

Comment: hi.. I have edited the code.. please check

Comment: i have no idea what is going on in your code. are you deleting and re-creating whole element whenever you want to push data into tree? that's wrong.  You should use bindings for this. example: `<paper-tree data="[[data]]"></paper-tree>` and then in script `this.push("data", .. some object ..)` but i am not sure if this fix your problem. I don't really much understand that code. maybe someone who know paper-tree more could help

Answer (score 0):

Polymer paper-tree have a data property. You just need to update it.

Help link: https://github.com/vpusher/paper-tree/blob/master/paper-tree.html